# How can I show and export different Jasper in JasperServer?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I want to show a PDF with one jrxml into the JasperServer (this is simple). But then, when the user click on "Export to PDF" I need to show some more fields in the generated PDF.

I don´t know If I can upload 2 different jrxml (one to show it and one to export it), or if I can pass a parameter so the jasper will know if it has to print the added fields.

Comment: @Jorge I have seen that Alex K, have found a duplicate (and it seems correct) consider to accept this duplicate, your question will remain (as search target), but it will also link to that answer.

Comment: Yes, I was checking right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the [net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.key.{suffix}](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.key.%7Bsuffix%7D)

The strategy would be to exclude the fields (reportElements) from all other export types then pdf

```
<jasperReport ...> 
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.exclude.key.myField"/>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.graphics2d.exclude.key.myField"/>
   ....
  <textField>
    <reportElement key="myField" x="45" y="35" width="125" height="20" uuid="5c2bb49a-ba95-4cb7-8c46-c32a0769e5e9"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
 </textField>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I don´t really need to hide that reportElements from all other export types, but I need to hide them from the previsualized PDF wich is shown before trying to export to any format.

Comment: @JorgeAndrésdelasCuevas I guess that is the html view?

Comment: Aha! Yes. It is the html view wich is shown directly in the JasperServer web application. So if I exclude it from the html export it should work fine?

Comment: @JorgeAndrésdelasCuevas it is worth a try : )

Comment: It works fine. Thank you very much!